# Não sei como fazer para passar de um opção para outra

Tags: python

**Tentei fazer nas primeiras linhas um menu que iria direcionar para uma ação se certo numero fosse digitado , mas aparece um erro do qual não sei como resolver**

---

```
def menupricip():
print ('#### Lucy_Main ####\n###################\n1°-Lista de Compras\n2°-Conversar\n3°-Calculadora Basica\n')
acao = int(input('Selecione a acao desejada : '))
if acao == 1:
            list()
            elif acao <=2:
                    dialog()



def list():
    numero_de_itens = input('Coloque o número de itens para o carrinho : ')
    lista_de_produtos = []
    ', '.join(lista_de_produtos)

    i = 1
    while i <= int(numero_de_itens): #chave prara repetição
        nome_do_produto = input('Nome do item # ' + str(i) + ': ')

        lista_de_produtos.append(nome_do_produto) # Produto adicionado na lista

        i += 1 #loop até atingir o número de produtos

    print('Serão', numero_de_itens, 'itens colocados no carrinho /n')

    print ('Revisão De Itens ')
    print (lista_de_produtos)
    a= input ('Tudo está correto ?')
    print (lista_de_produtos)

    def criarArquivo () :
            arquivo = open('lista.txt','w')
            arquivo.close()
    def escreveArquivo():
            arquivo = open('lista.txt', 'r+')
            arquivo.write(str(lista_de_produtos)) #converti em str
            arquivo.close()

    criarArquivo()
    escreveArquivo()



def dialog():
import random
print ('1 - mal \n2 - bem \n')
escolha = int(input('Como esta ?\n'))
if escolha == 1:
    sort = random.randint(1,8)
    if sort == 1:
        print ('A vida me ensinou a nunca desistir. \n Nem ganhar, nem perder mas procurar evoluir.')
        pass
    elif sort == 2:
        print ('Eu vou te dizer uma coisa que você já sabe \n : O mundo não é um grande arco-íris. É um lugar sujo, é um lugar cruel. Que não quer saber o quanto você é durão. \n Vai botar você de joelhos e você vai ficar de joelhos para sempre se você deixar. \n Você, eu, ninguém vai bater tão duro como a vida. \n Mas não se trata de bater duro. Se trata de quanto você aguenta apanhar \n e seguir em frente. O quanto você é capaz de aguentar e continuar tentando. \n É assim que se consegue vencer.')
        pass
    elif sort == 3:
        print ('Entregue o teu caminho ao Senhor , \n confia Nele e o mais Ele fara ! \n Salmos 37:5')
        pass
    elif sort == 4:
        print ('Se você sabe o seu valor, então vá atrás do que você merece. \n Mas tem que ter disposição para apanhar.\n E nada de apontar dedos, dizer que você não consegue por causa dele, dela ou de quem seja.\n Só covardes fazem isso e você não é covarde. Você é melhor do que isso!')
        pass
    elif sort == 5:
        print ('Nas grandes batalhas da vida, o primeiro passo para a vitória \n é o desejo de vencer.')
        pass
    elif sort == 6:
        print ('Se andarmos apenas por caminhos já traçados, \n chegaremos apenas aonde os outros chegaram.')
        pass
    elif sort == 7:
        print ('Aquele que tentou e não conseguiu \n é superior aquele que nada tentou.')
        pass
    elif sort == 8:
        print ('Não devemos ter medo dos confronto \n até os planetas se chocam, e do caos nascem as estrelas')
        pass
```

Comment: Qual erro? Por favor, revise as indentações no seu código no corpo da pergunta. Há várias linhas indentadas de forma errada.

Comment: Guilherme, seu problema não está muito claro. A questão do erro foi por falta de uma boa identação do código, porém, acredito que esta não é sua dúvida, pois o título da pergunta está um pouco fora do contexto em que descreveu o que realmente está com dúvidas. Se possível, nos explique claramente o que deseja que seu script faça, e vamos rever o código, adaptando.

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, o erro que estava acontecendo é pela má identação do código. Basta revisar e corrigir. Realizei aqui a alteração arrumando a identação - pois o python verifica o escopo dos blocos por meio destas - e alguns espaços vazios que havia deixado desnecessariamente.

```
def menupricip():
    print('#### Lucy_Main ####\n###################\n1°-Lista de Compras\n2°-Conversar\n3°-Calculadora Basica\n')
    acao = int(input('Selecione a acao desejada : '))
    if acao == 1:
        list()
    elif acao <= 2:
        dialog()


def list():
    numero_de_itens = input('Coloque o número de itens para o carrinho : ')
    lista_de_produtos = []
    ', '.join(lista_de_produtos)

    i = 1
    while i <= int(numero_de_itens):  # chave prara repetição
        nome_do_produto = input('Nome do item # ' + str(i) + ': ')

        lista_de_produtos.append(nome_do_produto)  # Produto adicionado na lista

        i += 1  # loop até atingir o número de produtos

    print('Serão', numero_de_itens, 'itens colocados no carrinho /n')

    print('Revisão De Itens ')
    print(lista_de_produtos)
    a = input('Tudo está correto ?')
    print(lista_de_produtos)

    def criarArquivo():
            arquivo = open('lista.txt','w')
            arquivo.close()

    def escreveArquivo():
            arquivo = open('lista.txt', 'r+')
            arquivo.write(str(lista_de_produtos))  # converti em str
            arquivo.close()

    criarArquivo()
    escreveArquivo()


def dialog():
    import random
    print('1 - mal \n2 - bem \n')
    escolha = int(input('Como esta ?\n'))
    if escolha == 1:
        sort = random.randint(1, 8)
        if sort == 1:
            print('A vida me ensinou a nunca desistir. \n Nem ganhar, nem perder mas procurar evoluir.')
            pass
        elif sort == 2:
            print('Eu vou te dizer uma coisa que você já sabe \n : O mundo não é um grande arco-íris. É um lugar sujo, é um lugar cruel. Que não quer saber o quanto você é durão. \n Vai botar você de joelhos e você vai ficar de joelhos para sempre se você deixar. \n Você, eu, ninguém vai bater tão duro como a vida. \n Mas não se trata de bater duro. Se trata de quanto você aguenta apanhar \n e seguir em frente. O quanto você é capaz de aguentar e continuar tentando. \n É assim que se consegue vencer.')
            pass
        elif sort == 3:
            print('Entregue o teu caminho ao Senhor , \n confia Nele e o mais Ele fara ! \n Salmos 37:5')
            pass
        elif sort == 4:
            print('Se você sabe o seu valor, então vá atrás do que você merece. \n Mas tem que ter disposição para apanhar.\n E nada de apontar dedos, dizer que você não consegue por causa dele, dela ou de quem seja.\n Só covardes fazem isso e você não é covarde. Você é melhor do que isso!')
            pass
        elif sort == 5:
            print('Nas grandes batalhas da vida, o primeiro passo para a vitória \n é o desejo de vencer.')
            pass
        elif sort == 6:
            print('Se andarmos apenas por caminhos já traçados, \n chegaremos apenas aonde os outros chegaram.')
            pass
        elif sort == 7:
            print('Aquele que tentou e não conseguiu \n é superior aquele que nada tentou.')
            pass
        elif sort == 8:
            print('Não devemos ter medo dos confronto \n até os planetas se chocam, e do caos nascem as estrelas')
            pass


def main():
    menupricip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```